# My random quiz generator is returning two questions

Tags: vb.net, random

my objective is to generate a random question ( +, * or -) and an answer when I click a button which I have been able to do. The problem is when I generate it, it returns a question(label) and an answer(MessageBox) but when I click ok on the messageBox it asks another question straight after and once I dismiss that messageBox it stops asking.

```
Private Sub Generate()

    'This is my first random value'
    Dim rnd1 As New Random
    'This is my Second random Value'
    Dim rnd2 As New Random
    'This value will decide weather it is a +, * or -'
    Dim rnd3 As New Random
    'Declaring first value as an integer'
    Dim Val1 As Integer
    'Declaring second value as an integer'
    Dim Val2 As Integer
    'This will calculate the answer'
    Dim Ans As Double
    'This is what I will reference to to display the question'
    Dim question As String

    'If the random value is equal to 1, the question is an addition'
    If (rnd3.Next(1, 3) = 1) Then
        Val1 = rnd1.Next(1, 20)
        Val2 = rnd2.Next(1, 25)
        Ans = Val1 + Val2
        question = Val1.ToString() + "+ " + Val2.ToString()
        lbl_ques.Text = question
        MessageBox.Show("Answer = " + Ans.ToString())
        Val1 = 0
        Val2 = 0
        Ans = 0
        question = ""

    End If

    'If the random value is equal to 2, the question is a multiplication'
    If (rnd3.Next(1, 3) = 2) Then
        Val1 = rnd1.Next(1, 10)
        Val2 = rnd2.Next(1, 17)
        Ans = Val1 * Val2
        question = Val1.ToString() + "* " + Val2.ToString()
        lbl_ques.Text = question
        MessageBox.Show("Answer = " + Ans.ToString())
        Val1 = 0
        Val2 = 0
        Ans = 0
        question = ""
    End If

    'If the random value is equal to 3, the question is a subtraction'
    If (rnd3.Next(1, 3) = 3) Then
        Val1 = rnd1.Next(1, 50)
        Val2 = rnd2.Next(1, 43)
        Ans = Val1 - Val2
        question = Val1.ToString() + "- " + Val2.ToString()
        lbl_ques.Text = question
        MessageBox.Show("Answer = " + Ans.ToString())
        Val1 = 0
        Val2 = 0
        Ans = 0
        question = ""
    End If


End Sub
```

How can I stop it from generating another question and answer straight away? Thanks

P.S If you are wondering why I am using VB it is because its for a school project and has to be in VB :/ I usually use c#

Comment: When it'll work, send it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ you'll get some good advice on how to polish your code.

Answer (score 1):

Either use

An exit sub to break out of the current subroutine

```
If ... Then

    Exit Sub
End If
```

or and ElseIf to only execute one of the If conditions

```
If ... Then

ElseIf ... Then

End If
```

or (preferably) a Select case statement

```
Select Case rnd.Next(1, 3)

Case 1

Case 2

Case 3

End Select
```

Side note you only need to create one Random object and just call .Next with the appropriate values each time